# Will driving six LEDs damage a PIC18F24K22 microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, pic

Can this microcontroller drive six 20mA LEDs at once or will it just fry?  Do I need to use transistors or not?

[Microcontroller datasheet.](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/PIC18F24K22)

Comment: It probably won't fry, but it may not work.  How would we know without knowing anything about the LEDs?  Are they 2 mA indicator LEDs, or 300 W illumination LEDs?

Comment: I would be using 20 mA LEDs, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: What does the datasheet say regarding the maximum current of a single output and the maximum total current the chip can handle? [Edit] the datasheet link into your question.

Comment: The 20mA on the LED datasheet is probably the maximum current, not the recommended current. For indicator use most modern LEDs only need a few mA to appear bright to the human eye. Experiment with the series resistor to see what current you actually need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you'll be safe, so long as the microcontroller never exceeds 85 degrees C. Page 414 of the datasheet specifies the maximum electrical properties that are relevant here:

[image: snip of datasheet]

Six 20mA LEDs will be 120mA, which is below the source or sink limits for temperatures below 85.

Comment: Thank you all a lot for trying to help me out here !

Answer (score 0):

My eyes cannot see what microcontroller you have but the solution is relative easy. Get the data sheet and find the maximum current each pin will supply (sink source depending on LED polarity). Next you will to find the maximum current the microcontroller can tolerate, for many it is 200 mA total for all pins with each pin allowed 20mA maximum. If I were doing the design i would size my resistor to supply no more than 50% of its capacity and the total is no more than 50% of the microcontroller.  These are consecutive numbers, as I do not know your ambient conditions. Exceeding the maximum ratings will destroy  your microcontroller.